# The correct way to use Include<TResult, TInclude>

Tags: ravendb

I have two classes (they are persisted in RavenDB):

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    public DateTime GameTime { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public int HomeTeamScore { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamScore { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? PositionInGroup { get; set; }
    public int? PositionInPlayOffs { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
}
```

I want to output all the games with the team name, date and location like this:

> Poland - Greece, 2012-06-08 18:00:00 - Warsaw (POL)

I know I could include the home team name and away team name in the Game entity, but instead of doing that I want to use the Include RavenDB include functionality.

I wrote this code:

```
// Print the schedule
var games = session
    .Query<Game>()
    .Customize(c => c.Include<Game, Team>(i => i.Id))
    .OrderBy(x => x.GameTime)
    .ToList();


foreach (var g in games)
{
    var homeTeam = session.Load<Team>(g.HomeTeamId);
    var awayTeam = session.Load<Team>(g.AwayTeamId);
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Format("{0} - {1}, {2} - {3}",
        homeTeam.Name,
        awayTeam.Name,
        g.GameTime,
        g.Location));
}
```

If I understand things correct, when I load the home team and away team in the loop a get request should not be issued to the server? But when I look in the logs I can see this:

> Request #1 654: GET     -     0 ms - Euro2012   - 200 - /docs/teams/34
>
> Document with key 'teams/34' was found

The first request issued to the server looks like this:

> Request #1 648: GET     -     5 ms - Euro2012   - 200 - /indexes/dynamic/Games?query=&start=0&pageSize=128&aggregation=None&sort=GameTime&include=Id(teams/)

So it looks like the teams should be "included"

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Customize() piece of the query. You can do Include() by itself. Does this help: http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2012/03/keeping-domain-model-pure-with-ravendb.html?

Comment: I don't get the Include method on the Query, do you reference any spec. assembly? I added the RavenDB Client to my project

Comment: Include() is an IRavenQueryable, and it's in the Raven.Client.Lightweight assembly.

Comment: For some reason I had a reference to the F# Raven library so I couldn't add a using directive to Raven.Client.Linq. I will try my code again. Thank you.

Comment: I change my code to `var games = session
                        .Query<Game>()
                        .Include<Game, Team>(x => x.HomeTeamId)
                        .Include<Game, Team>(x => x.AwayTeamId)
                        .ToList();` And now I cannot see that any more request are being sent to the server after after this request. Thank you.

Comment: That's the beauty of Include(); there should only be one request. To populate the data, you'll need to access the session, like what was done on that link I sent you. Did you try that?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, **now it works**. That is one request.

Comment: Ah, good! So, if I post this as an answer, you can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the Customize() piece of the query. You can do Include() by itself. An example is here:

http://inaspiralarray.blogspot.com/2012/03/keeping-domain-model-pure-with-ravendb.html

Include() is an IRavenQueryable, and it's in the Raven.Client.Lightweight assembly.

Answer (score 3):

You are including the wrong id, you need:

```
.Customize(c => c.Include<Game, Team>(i => i.AwayTeamId ))
.Customize(c => c.Include<Game, Team>(i => i.HomeTeamId ))
```

Comment: Should I use the .Customize or the .Include on the Query? Difference?